# using functions to write the code in C++

Tags: c++

Hi i'm trying to Write a program in C++ to, generate and print 20 random numbers, between 0 to 999, and do the following operations without using inbuilt functions, find and print the: min value, max value, average, median, standard deviation, variance. Do a binary search on the 15th element. Please help me with the code.

So far i've done this much
    #include 
    #include 
    #include

```
using namespace std;
void minimum(int[], int);
void maximum (int[], int);
void average(int[], int);
void median(int[], int);
void mean(int[], int);
void sort(int[], int);


int ra()
{
int r = rand() % 1000;
return r;
}

int main ()
{

srand(time(NULL));
ra();
int array[20];
int num=20;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
array[i] = ra();
cout << "Index: " << i << ", random number: " <<  array[i] << endl;
}

minimum();
new_array[20];
num=20;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
new_array[i] = new_array();
cout << "Index: " << i << ", random number: " <<  minimum << endl;

} 
return 0;

}

void minimum(int new_array[], int num)
{
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num; i++)
if (new_array[i] minimum)
minimum = new_array[i];
cout << "Maximum value: " << minimum << endl;


}   
void maximum (int new_array[], int num)
{  
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num; i++)
if (new_array[i] > maximum)
maximum = new_array[i];
cout << "Maximum value: " << maximum << endl;


return 0;

}

void median(int new_array[], int num)
{
//CALCULATE THE MEDIAN (middle number)
if(num % 2 != 0){// is the # of elements odd?
int temp = ((num+1)/2)-1;
cout << "The median is " << new_array[temp] << endl;
 }
 else{// then it's even! :)
 cout << "The median is "<< new_array[(num/2)-1]<<new_array[num/2]< endl;             
 }
 mean(new_array, num);

 }

 void sort(int new_array[], int num)
 {
 //ARRANGE VALUES
 for(int x=0; x<num; x++){
 for(int y=0; y<num-1; y++){
 if(new_array[y]>new_array[y+1]){
 int temp = new_array[y+1];
 new_array[y+1] = new_array[y];
 new_array[y] = temp;
 }
 }
 }
 cout << "List: ";
 for(int i =0; i<num; i++){
 cout << new_array[i] << " ";
 }
 cout << "\n";
 median(new_array, num);

 }


void average_(int new_array[], int nums)
{
float sum;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{   
 sum+=num;
}
 cout << "Average value: " << average_/num << endl;   

}          


Please tell the necessary corrections
```

Comment: Did you compile the code? http://rextester.com/CYLZT48698

Comment: yes i did its showing prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:22:19: error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)()' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
     int random_ = ra;
                   ^

Comment: Then you want to solve the compile error? Not "but when i use function it is returning the value 0" ?

Comment: You know how to call a parameter-less function (as evidenced by `rand()`)  but somehow forgot how to do it when calling your own function.

Comment: I'm a beginner in C++, it will be very helpful if someone can help.

Comment: @Dhanushbharadawaj We want to help you too. So please, describe your problem clearly, provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which could be used to reproduce the issue, and tell us what do you want to do (the intent). See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I want to know what i'm doing wrong when calling the function in main function?

Comment: @Dhanushbharadawaj `random_ = ra;` should be `random_ = ra();`.

Comment: You will need to provide a seed for the `rand()` function to use by calling `srand(time(NULL))` (Or perhaps not need but should)

Comment: Then the output i'm getting is 0

Comment: is it necessary to use the strand function.....I don't want to use it

Comment: @Dhanushbharadawaj No, it won't. There's another compile error with `return(r);`.

Comment: @songyuanyao  If i give it as return r ;    it will again give 0, if i give it as return r(); it will throw  error: 'r' cannot be used as a function

Comment: @Dhanushbharadawaj, The purpose of `srand` is to make `rand` produce different numbers every time you run your program when used as `srand(time(NULL))`. Otherwise you will get the same sequence of random numbers each time

Comment: ya i understood the purpose i've changed the code now it looks like this

Answer (score 1):

You have a ways to go, your code does not do any of the things you want yet. However, you mentioned that you are a beginner so I fixed your code and set up a basic structure of how to get going. I left comments on what I changed and what you need to do. That being said, I don't know what you mean by "Do a binary search on the 15th element"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int ra()
{
    // You wanted a number between 0 and 999 inclusive so do not add 1
    // Instead do a modulus of 1000
    int r = rand() % 1000;
    return r;
}

int main ()
{
    // Do this to get different random numbers each time you run your program
    srand(time(NULL));

    // You have to call ra as a function. Do this by writing: ra()
    // Here I am storing 20 random numbers in an array
    int nums[20];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        nums[i] = ra();
        cout << "Index: " << i << ", random number: " <<  nums[i] << endl;
    }

    // Iterate to find the minimum number
    int minimum = nums[0];
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < 20; ++i)
        if (nums[i] < minimum)
            minimum = nums[i];
    cout << "Minimum value: " << minimum << endl;

    // TODO: Find the maximum in basically the same way

    // TODO: Find the average by summing all numbers then dividing by 20

    // TODO: Find the median by sorting nums and taking the average of the two center elements

    // TODO: etc.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for correcting the code i understood where i was making mistake,

Comment: About the binary search i think we have to search for the 15th number in the array through binary search.

Comment: @Dhanushbharadawaj, I would say go through all the exercises you mentioned on your own other than the binary search and then make another question about just the binary search

Comment: Sure i will do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int r;
int ra;
int i=0;

int ra(){

r = (rand() % 999) + 1;

return r;
}

int main ()
{
int random_;

srand((int)time(0));

while (i++ < 20)
{
    random_ = r;
    cout<< random_<<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```